# How to assign lines from a text file to different kind of variables

Tags: c#, variables, streamreader

Had some trouble with reading and then storing the lines from a text file.

Need to make a map program, where the user can make a plan how to travel from A-B with metros. I need to store the names of the metro stations and the number of metro stations per line.

The format is: (where number is the number of station per line and text is the name of the stations

```
3
abc
dba
efg
2
asd
dfdf
5
sad
dff
asf
dgh
dfgh
```

So when a number appear it's a new line.

I already tried .split(\n) but this only works if I want to store all the lines in string. But the goal is to store the numbers in `int` and store the names in `string`.

Comment: Well once you've got the numbers as strings, you can use `int.Parse` to convert them to integers...

Comment: One thing not directly related: I'd simplify this in only having the station numbers in that file. The names wouldn't change much, would they? And they are likely to be unique per station number, right (1:1-Relation)? So you can use a lookup table for those. So, in allowing the user to input number _and_ name, you open up to typing mistakes and relational mishaps ( number - name mismatch ).

Comment: Also: Can station names contain numbers? ( Like "2 2nd district" or "5 Main Ave and 3rd Street")

Comment: Also, you could always use `JSON` to store station numbers in one dict and station names in another.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            List<List<string>> stationNames = new List<List<string>>();

            List<string> lineNames = null;
            string line = "";
            int count = 0;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    count = int.Parse(line);
                    lineNames = new List<string>();
                    stationNames.Add(lineNames);
                }
                else
                {
                    lineNames.Add(line.Trim());
                    count--;
                }
            }
        }
```